# More efficient way to find consecutive numbers in vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I need to write a program to print the line numbers, in ascending order, of a particular word in a file. Example output of the program would be:

```
 Hello 1, 3, 5-6, 8, 10-15.
// 5-6 represents 5, 6 (consecutive numbers)
```

The line numbers are stored in a sorted `vector<int>` with no duplicates. I have created a solution, but my instincts tell me I can do better. I would appreciate some feedback. Further, the following code only processes the line numbers. The word is found in another method.

```
void IndexPager::createLines(vector<int>& vec, string& line)
{
  int start = *vec.begin(), end = -1, offset = 0; // initial offset to start

  for (vector<int>::const_iterator itr = vec.begin();
       itr != vec.end() + 1; itr++)
  {
    if (*itr == start + offset && itr != vec.end())
    {
      end = *itr;
      ++offset;
    } // check if line numbers are consecutive and not reading at end of vector
    else // not consecutive
    {
      if ((end != -1) && (end != start))
      {
        line.append(intToString(start) + "-");
        line.append(intToString(end));
      } // if there existed consecutive numbers, display with dash
        // must be difference of at least 1
      else // else, there were no consecutive numbers
        line.append(intToString(start));

      if (itr != vec.end()) // check if not at end of vector
        line.append(", ");
      else // reached end of vector
        line.append(".");

      start = *itr; // set start to next line number. Soft reset.
      offset = 1; // change default offset to 1. 0 for first case.
      end = -1;
    } // not consecutive
  } // Get all line numbers and format for proper output
} // createLines()
```

Comment: If you want some feedback on working code, consider posting it over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. However, you will have to include a fully compilable solution; read the help center: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a couple of observations.

1. you're assuming the vector length is > 0
2. vec.end()+1 might not give you the result you expect, depending on the vector implementation.

incrementing itr at the start of your loop body instead of at the end using for solves both of these issues.

on efficiency, you could try replacing "start+offset" with "next"

```
void IndexPager::createLines(vector<int>& vec, string& line)
{
    int start,end,next;
    vector<int>::const_iterator itr = vec.begin();
    next=end=start=*itr;
    while(itr!=vec.end())
    {
        ++itr;
        end=next++;
        if(itr==vec.end()||next!=*itr)
        {
            // break in consecutive sequence
            line.append(intToString(start));
            if(end!=start){
                line.append("-");
                line.append(intToString(end));
            }
            if(itr!=vec.end())
            {
                line.append(", ");
            }
            next=end=start=*itr;
        }
    } // Get all line numbers and format for proper output
    line.append(".");
} // createLines()
```

itr is still checked against vec.end() three times per iteration, so you might want to repeat the break-in-sequence section at the end of the loop and use a normal for(auto i:vec) instead, but that said compiler optimisation might eliminate the repetition